# batch scripting to compare and move files in a folder to another based on a part of source file name

Tags: batch-file

Please help me with following problem which I am trying to solve.

I have triplet of source files would have the following names:

```
2d09089d-ce5a-47dd-a2f5-4ee1c8c9efa5_test1_test2_fg_nel_dd tel.CSV
2d09089d-ce5a-47dd-a2f5-4ee1c8c9efa5_test1_test2_fg_nel_dd tel.CSV.MOD
2d09089d-ce5a-47dd-a2f5-4ee1c8c9efa5_test1_test2_fg_nel_dd tel temp.TKT
```

There is a corresponding file would be named:

```
78256_2d09089d-ce5a-47dd-a2f5-4ee1c8c9efa5_test1_test2_fg_nel_dd tel.trc
```

I need a batch script to match up the corresponding file (.trc) with the corresponding triplet of source files, then move the triplet of source files to another directory.  The length of the file names of the source files will vary as they include different company names.  So one way I thought it could be done is if the script either ignored or truncated off the first six characters of trigger file name, then did the match on the next 36 characters.

Following was tried with no luck.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for %%g in ('*.CSV *.MOD *.TKT') do  (
    set var1=%%~g
    set var2= !var1:~0,36!
    for %%a in (*.trc) do (
        set var3=%%~a
        set var4= !var3:~0,36!

    if  !var2! equ !var4! (COPY "%%g" "C:\dest" >nul)
        ) 
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following is my completed script and it works.

```
for /f "tokens=*" %%1 in ('dir /a-d /b *.*') do (
    set filename=%%1&set match1=!filename:~0,36!
       echo !match1!
       for /f "tokens=*" %%A in ('dir /a-d /b *.ctrl') do (
          set filename2=%%A&set match2=!filename2:~0,36!
                      echo !match2!      
        if "!match2!" == "!match1!" if not %%~x1==.ctrl MOVE "%%1" "C:\dest" >nul
    )        
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is incomplete.

You said that "the trigger file name" are the files with `.trc` extension. This means that the files that must be processed are the files with `.trc` extension and the other files don't matters.

You said that you need "a batch script to match up the corresponding file (.trc) with the corresponding triplet of source files". You didn't specified what happen if there are *more or less files* than "the triplet" that match the corresponding `.trc` file, so I guess that *no matters* how many files match the one with `.trc` extension: just move them all!

You didn't specified what to do with the processed `*.trc` files.

In the question title you said "move files", but in the example code you use "COPY files".

The next Batch file process the `*.trc` files and copy *all matching files* to other directory:

```
@echo off
setlocal

rem Process all files with ".trc" extension
rem take just the file name after the first underscore character
for /F "tokens=1* delims=_" %%a in ('dir /B *.trc') do (

   rem Copy all matching files to other directory
   copy "%%~Nb.*" "C:\dest" >nul

)
```

If this code don't solve your problem, then you must be *much more clear* when describe the details of your problem...